# postman: changing pre-request script dyncamically during a collection run

Tags: scripting, postman, postman-collection-runner

There are certain functions I would like to run as pre-request script for certain requests and not others.I would like to do this without having to repeat the code for all requests using the UI, but in one place - maybe the pre-request script for the collection. Does the sandbox allow access to the runtime, so that I can maybe defined this as the pre-request script of the first request.

something like `currentRun.collection['someRequest'].pre = () => {console.log("hello world!")}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the collection and add pre-request script there .

inside collection pre-request , you can add if condition like

```
if (pm.info.requestName==="request1"){

   do this

} else if (pm.info.requestName==="request2"){

   do this
}
```

Another option is to save the function as environment variable and call eval on it:

```
eval(pm.environment.get("variablename"))
```